# Slide content to the left, offscreen

Tags: jquery, html, slider

First http://wojoweb.pl/strony/pkpcargo/

I want to slide or scroll content to the left/right.

## Html

```
       <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tempus enim pellentesque suscipit ornare.</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tempus enim pellentesque suscipit ornare. Curabitur malesuada non ipsum ut venenatis. Fusce tristique, urna interdum venenatis congue, arcu dui rhoncus odio.</div>

            <div class="col-md-3">Sed dolor dui, sollicitudin vitae convallis ut, viverra vitae mauris. Sed quis egestas lacus. Pellentesque dictum ligula id justo porta condimentum. Etiam convallis dolor dui, a molestie nisi elementum vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

            <div class="col-md-3">Aenean quis mi eget augue suscipit cursus dictum eget est. Phasellus tempus nisi sit amet dui sollicitudin, vitae lacinia massa tempor. Aenean sit amet metus ut orci faucibus condimentum vitae mattis nisi. Nam volutpat turpis quis sapien molestie, nec dapibus elit interdum.</div>
        </div>
```

At the bottom of the text will be navgation (like navigation at top left corner). It should sliding by two columns (col-md-3). Anyone can give me advice how to do it? or show me good example.

Slider should go offscreen to the left or right.

Answer (score 0):

there's your solution. It animates element's left property.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $lefty = $('#yourelement').next();
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() :
        0
  });
});
```

Copied from http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/